# Django redirect from inside a view

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-views

I'm using django 1.11.8.

I need to perform some check on the requested view and inside it redirect the user to another Http page, but this code fail, as the redirect is ignored.

What am I missing?

```
class ThisCreateView(CreateView):

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
         if self.kwargs['x'] == 1:
              return redirect(reverse('this_app:this_list'))
         return kwargs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return a redirect from the `get_form_kwargs` method. Its job is to return a dictionary of kwargs for the form.

You could move this check to the [`dispatch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch) method.

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     if kwargs['x'] == 1:
          # note you don't need to call reverse when you use redirect
          return redirect('this_app:this_list')
     return super(ThisCreateView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Or you could just drop the class-based view and use a plain function  view which makes the execution flow much easier to read and understand (and to change if necessary).

Answer (score 1):

Solution from @Alasdair worked perfectly for me albeit with a small change:

```
return super(ThisCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```